# CakePHP Bake association problem

Tags: cakephp, code-generation, associations

I have only two tables in my database with a one-to-many relationship between them (user hasMany messages) and am trying to get basic CRUD functionality going. Bake detects the associations correctly and specifies them correctly inside the model classes, but in controllers and views it looks like Cake doesn't know anything about those associations -- I don't even get a select tag for user_id when I go add a new message. Has anyone come across this problem before? What can I be doing wrong?

Table structure appears to be fine:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
created datetime NOT NULL,
modified datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`content` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`modified` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Please post what are you doing exactly in the controller, what is what you get, and what is missing.

Comment: Your associations are in your model, not in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the console to bake your MVC files you could try that.

First bake the model files. Then bake the controller files using scaffold.

Then bake the view files.

Finally go back and bake the controller files without scaffold.

This should get you all basic CRUD functionality with all the associations you may have.

Hope that helps ...